# How to reference FormGroup inside FormArray without *ngFor: I'm getting errors

Tags: angular, angular6

I have 2 FormGroup's inside a FormArray

```
setRubricaDosForm: FormGroup;

ngOnInit() {
  this.setRubricaDosForm = this.fb.group({
    rubrica: this.fb.array([
      this.fb.group({
        nombreUno: ["", Validators.required],
        puntajeUno: [
          "",
          [Validators.required, Validators.pattern("/^-?(0|[1-9]d*)?$/")]
        ]
      }),
      this.fb.group({
        nombreDos: ["", Validators.required],
        puntajeDos: [0]
      })
    ])
  });
```

}

```
//a getter for the array controls
get rubrica(){
  return this.setRubricaDosForm.get('rubrica') as FormArray;
}
```

Then in my template i have this.

```
<form [formGroup]="setRubricaDosForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="submit()">
  <div formArrayName="rubrica">
    //here i've also tried formGroupName="setRubricasDosForm.controls[0].get('rubrica').controls[0]
    <div [formGroupName]="rubrica.controls[0]"> 
      <input formControlName="nombreUno">
      <input formControlName="puntajeUno">
    </div>
    <div [formGroupName]="rubrica.controls[1]"> 
      <input formControlName="nombreDos">
      <input formControlName="puntajeDos">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I get `ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'rubrica -> [object Object]'`

With the commented way I get that `there's no get method`

I don't use *ngFor because I just need those 2 FormGroup's and I wanted to put them inside a FormArray, I haven't tried declaring two different FormGroups from start (I want to do it this way unless there is no way of doing it).

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are directly referencing a FormGroup with `rubrica.controls[0]` so use `[formGroup]` instead of the`[formGroupName]` and it should work like a charm.

### Results

```
<form [formGroup]="setRubricaDosForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="submit()">
  <div formArrayName="rubrica">
    <div [formGroup]="rubrica.controls[0]"> 
      <input formControlName="nombreUno">
      <input formControlName="puntajeUno">
    </div>
    <div [formGroup]="rubrica.controls[1]"> 
      <input formControlName="nombreDos">
      <input formControlName="puntajeDos">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Geeeniuss Geeenius, sign it with Mr. Deeds movie scene melody. Thanks Man